# Changing text color UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, email, contact-list

Hi i'm working on an iOS project that uses the MFMailComposeViewController to send out an email.

I changed the title bar to use an image

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"project_headerbg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

but now when I click on the '+' button next to CC I can't read the text "Choose a contact to mail" in the header very well and was wondering if there was a way to change the color of that text?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with using the `MFMailComposeViewController`. If you wish to customize the appearance of a `UINavigationBar`, then you may need to set more properties than just the background image. You should also setup the `titleTextAttributes`.

```
// Use whatever color is appropriate
NSDictionary *attributes = @{ UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor blueColor] };
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
```

There are other attributes such as the font and shadow colors. Feel free to set the ones you need.

Comment: Thank You so much, it worked it allows me to change the color of the text.
PS. The correct method name is setTitleTextAttributes the order of title and text needed to be reverse otherwise this works.

Comment: Oops - sorry for the typo - I'll update my answer with the correct name.